How do I make this templated class be a friend of another class?
I'm trying to get access to members from another templated class and it doesn't let me. The issue is I don't know why.
#include <iostream>
    
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct Obj{};
    
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct Obj2
{
    template <typename U0, typename U1, typename U2, typename U3> 
    friend Obj<U0, U1, U2, U3>;
    
    template <typename T> 
    Obj2(Obj<T, T0, T1, T2> const&) {}
};
    
int main() {}

Output:
<source>:10:31: error: expected unqualified-id before ';' token [-Wtemplate-body]
   10 |     friend Obj<U0, U1, U2, U3>;
      |                               ^
Compiler returned: 1

Godbolt link: code
Is this even doable?

@wohlstad yes, any template types.

You mean like in cppreference - Template friends examples?

@Saitama10000 I posted an answer with both options.

@wohlstad can you add the third option of only some parameters? thank you :)

I assume you want Obj with any template types to be a friend.
This means that any instantiation of Obj will be a friend of Obj2.
In this case the proper syntax is:
template <typename U0, typename U1, typename U2, typename U3> 
friend struct Obj;

Live demo 1
If on the other hand you wish only Obj with template types that match those of Obj2 to be a friend, the syntax for that is:
friend struct Obj<T0,T1,T2,T3>;

Live demo 2

i'm sorry if it's a dumb question but what if I want only some parameters of Obj to be a friend?

So the reason is I can leave Obj without template parameters because they are deduced?

@Saitama10000 making only some types match is more tricky. There might be a way to do it, but at the moment I cannot think of a proper way. Maybe you'd like to post a new question for that ? (since the current question seems to be solved).

thank you, I will if I need it. I understand it's more involved.

It's not that they are deduced, it's that each instantiation of Obj is a friend of each instantiation of Obj2. The second demo is different, only the instantiation Obj<T0,T1,T2,T3> is a friend of Obj2<T0,T1,T2,T3>.

@Caleth yes, this difference is what I attempted to explain in my answer.
